# C# - Distributing COM DLLS

Tags: c#, dll, com

I have recently distributed an Application that uses a COM DLL (Skype4COM), and one of my clients says that the program errors out when they run it, mentioning something about retrieving the COM class factory. How do I distribute COM DLLs with an application, so the application can call it properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to register the COM DLL as part of your application's installation.

That being said, if it's a 3rd party COM library, such as Skype4COM, this should be installed as part of Skype's installation.  You likely need to check for this at runtime, and tell the user to install (the proper version of) Skype if it is not installed.

Comment: I've been debugging this on my laptop, which has Skype installed (Obviously, How I added the reference to the COM DLL in my app) in user-mode (Not within visual studio). However, despite my Skype installation, it still throws the error. Any suggestions?